# What is the correct place to validate data coming from the backend in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, flux, redux-thunk

Say I receive this JSON:

```
"events": [
            {
              "description": "Some event",
              "details": "Issue found",
              "id": 0,
              "severity": "critical",
              "type": "blabla"
            },
]
```

and I have a `Component` which uses the `severity` field to define its CSS class (something like `className={e.serveity}`);

If I receive a `severity` that is not among the expected ones (like **critical**, **warning**, etc), I would like to perform some action, like rendering another component or doing something else entirely.

What is the correct place to put this **validation** code? Should it be:

1. within the `Component` itself;
2. within the `action` in charge of the Promise;
3. within the `reducer`;

Comment: You could validate the data in a data store component. It would probably make sense to store it as a Component. Are you doing anything else with the flag?

Comment: I'd go with the action, you can easily dispatch another action if you want your application to take another route in that case

Comment: @Demon I use it in a `.reduce()` function within the same component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do that in component and within component you can do that in either react provided life cycle methods like componentWillMount, componentDidMount, componentWillReceiveProps and render.

Please note componentWillMount and componentWillReceiveProps are deprecated from latest React v16.3.

So you can do that depend on the need

If you want to do in render then

```
render(){
     this.state.events.map(item => {
          if(item != “critical” && item != “warning”){
                 //do stuff here
          }
     });
     return(

     );
   }
```

There are many ways to do such logic with in the component. So to your question the recommended place is component.

Actions are meant for dispatching an action and reducer is meant for setting the data in Redux state.